# Question Ban, Incorrect?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have just received a question ban on Stack Overflow. I'm not really sure why: I've asked a lot of questions with a zero score, and I got a few downvotes, but about as many as I got upvotes. I have a lot of zero score answers too.

I only have one downvote on answers and quite a few upvotes.

Why would I be question banned? Did I answer too many questions with quick answers that didn't get any score?

Comment: Have you asked any questions that have since been deleted?

Comment: 1, it had about a -5 score. I think.

Comment: I just got one upvote, and it unbanned me. so I was on the edge.

Comment: Never mind, someone downvoted the question too. :( Can't post now.

Comment: You have two older deleted questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932272/how-to-make-a-hard-drive-bootable , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185531/scanner-skipping-input-even-after-nextline-is-called which work against you. I'm not sure if they're worth undeleting, but maybe the off-topic one could be edited into shape. You might be able to write the community team and get the one you removed after finding your mistake dissociated from your account. In any case, you're right on the edge, so improvements to any of your questions could put you over.

Answer (score 7):

I was on the very edge of being post-banned. I haven't had the best scores, and those scores have brought me down low. So I need to be careful about what I post.

Comment: You had one question which was very negatively scored, deleted, and could not possibly be salvaged. It was about programming, you just didn't realize that 'poll' type questions weren't on-topic here. I've disassociated that from your account, you should not have to worry about the block kicking in again. Sorry about that :) You tend to, well, ask decent questions. Once in a while _one_ can just become like a lead weight you can't shake, we're fixing that.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I wasn't very careful in reading the help center at that point and hadn't yet found the "On Topic" article. I found that and it helped a lot.